# 'Classic' looking 11 speed brifters?

Tags: brifters

I'm building a Crust Lightning Bolt in the new light blue. I want to put 2 x 11 speed brifters on it but I'm struggling to find something that fits the look of a classic rando bike, e.g. silver levers. I've given up finding brown hoods. Gearing will be 2by but I'll settle for 1by and a bar end shifter for the front. Prefer Shimano compatible.
Any suggestions for a more classy looking brifters over all the black plastic looking ones? Older and used is fine, ideally under $200
Shimano

Comment: Shimano 105 ST-5800 and ST-R7000 were produced in Silver and are quite commonly seen.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: The 105 R7000 brifters seem to be produced in black and silver. https://bike.shimano.com/fr-FR/product/component/shimano105-r7000/ST-R7000-R.html

--

Also, in 2022, Shimano made a limited edition of the GRX groupset with a silver look: https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/grx-limited.html

It's available in 2x11 or 1x11, with the combinations that you can find at the "810" level of GRX. As of January 2024, it looks like it's still possible to buy it online - at least the whole groupset, I imagine that finding components separately will be harder.

However, mounting them on a older frame (that supposedly have rim brakes) will probably be an issue, as they are only available for hydraulic brakes.

Answer (score 2):

Campagnolo Athena is the only (certainly the last) polished aluminum 2x11 groupset that I know of. I think 2014 was the last year it was produced in polished aluminum, and it's pretty desirable among classic bike aficionados for exactly that reason.

Obviously that's not Shimano-compatible, but it can be adapted with a Jtek converter.

I have also heard of people [removing black anodization](https://theradavist.com/tutorial-how-to-remove-anodizing-and-polish-bicycle-components/) [from their parts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pnXa5tY6Ve8) for a classic look.

Comment: What about Centaur? Very silver (if not very polished) and current.

Comment: I didn't think of that. Good call.